# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)

Tags: permissions, ssh

I'm on a corp network. Basically a host with full domain name `hello.company.com` has an alias `hello`:

```
$ host hello
hello.company.com
```

`$ ssh hello.company.com` works well.

But if I try `$ ssh hello` I get

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

What might be the cause of this problem?